# Add a class to the <p> tag for a field of a ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am using a ModelForm with an extra field `my_field`:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    my_field = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

In the template, I display the form with the `as_p()` function.  With the code above, it renders the extra field as:

```
<p><label for="id_my_field">My field :</label> <input id="id_my_field" name="my_field" type="text" /></p>
```

How can I add a class to the `<p>` tag for this field only?  I would like:

```
<p class="special_field"><label ...
```

By looking at django/forms/forms.py, it seems that I have to use css_classes, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

1) render fields manually https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually

2) override `as_p` method:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def as_p(self):
        ...
```

3) if you want customise forms with minimal changes, look at the `django-crispy-forms` http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to give different css class for required field, define [`required_css_class`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.required_css_class) attribute:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    my_field = forms.CharField()

    required_css_class = 'special_field'  # <----

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```